# Is there a WPF control that can perform CRUD operations a Domain Model?

Tags: wpf, crud

I am tasked with writing a WPF app that performs crud on 100 or so odd tables that are related.

I would have to write everything by hand.

My goal is to put a control in a WPF window, point it to the Domain Model and control allows users to perform CRUD operations.

Are there any out there that exist.  I have spent some time looking and can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the DataGrid from the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thanks!  Well look into this.

Answer (score 0):

May this control help you [WPFCrudControl](https://github.com/GenericCodes/WPFCrudControl)

A generic WPF CrudControl implemented based on the MVVM pattern. It gives a huge productivity boost for straightforward CRUD operations (Add, Edit, Delete, Validate, Listing with sorting, paging and searching). The control abstracts both the UI and business logic, so it requires relatively minimal coding effort, while keeping it possible to customize its behavior.